# Invertibility of a continuous operator minus its adjoint

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, duality-theorems

I am working on this functional analysis exercise:

---

Is the following proposition true?

$X$ is a Banach space, and $A: X \rightarrow X^{*}$ be a bounded linear
operator. Let $B=\left.A^{*}\right|_{X} .$ If $B-A$ is surjective, then there exists $M>0$ such that
$$
\|x\|_{X} \leq M\|A x-B x\|_{X^{*}}, \text{for all }x \in X
$$

---

I first want to determine the operator $C=B-A:X\to X^*$:

For every $f_v \in X^{**}$, $g\in X$, we have $\langle A^*v,g\rangle=\langle A^*f_v,g \rangle=\langle f_v,Ag\rangle=(Ag)v$. Therefore $(Bx)v=(Av)x$. Hence $C: X\to X^*,\ x\mapsto C_x\in X^*$ such that $C_xv=(Av)x-(Ax)v$.

I also know that the statement is true iff $C$ has an continuous inverse.

So how to prove if $C$ is invertible or not?

Comment: $A^*$ maps from $X^{**}$ to $X^*$. So, how can you possibly restrict $A^*$ to $X$? Do you mean the image of the fundamental mapping?

Comment: Yeah, just look $X$ as a subspace of $X^{**}$ using the canonical injection: $J:\ X \to X^{**},\ v \mapsto f_v$ such that $\langle f_v,g\rangle=\langle g,v\rangle$ for all $g\in X^{*}$.

Comment: Very nice exercise! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $T : X\to X^*$ let us denote $T^+ = T^*|_X$. As you saw already, $(T^+x)y = (Ty)x$ for $x,y\in X$.

Now, if $T$ is surjective, then $T^+$ is injective. Indeed, let $T^+x = 0$. Then $(Ty)x = 0$ for all $y\in X$ and so $x^*(x) = 0$ for all $x^*\in X^*$, which implies $x=0$, since
$$
\|x\| = \sup\{|x^*(x)| : x^*\in X^*,\,\|x^*\|=1\}.
$$
For $x,y\in X$ we also have
\begin{align}
[(A^+-A)^+x]y
&= [(A^+-A)y]x\\
&= (A^+y)x - (Ay)x\\
&= (Ax)y-(A^+x)y\\
&= [(A-A^+)x]y.
\end{align}
Thus $A^+-A = -(A^+-A)^+$ is injective and the claim is true by the [bounded inverse theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_inverse_theorem).